# Suspend Data without LMS - Articulate Storyline

Tags: asp.net, scorm, articulate-storyline

I work for a small company that is using a custom built web system using ASP.NET that hosts a number of learning tools, including articulate storyline courses.

We have an SQL database that stores the learner variables from the storyline courses, which works well. However this only works if a user completes the course in one go. If the user logs out of their account half way through their course and uses another device to log back in, they would lose their progress.

There is a Suspend Data function that we would like to make use of, I have seen this work with LMS's, but we want to keep our system as it is. As ours isn't an off the shelf LMS and we don't have a system that complies to SCORM, our developer is struggling to find out how we can capture the users Suspend Data that gets fired on every slide. We want to capture this so that when a user logs back into their account we can resume them to the point where they left off if they log out.

Has anyone in the past used Suspend Data without an LMS? Any advice would be greatly received.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: How are you determining completion? Presumably you have at least some of the SCORM RTE implemented.

Comment: Your content is searching for the API (SCORM 1.2) or API_1484_11 (SCORM 2004) from the LMS.  Since it doesn’t sound like you expose it currently you’d need to roll one together or buy one.  You’ve mostly only got buy options as I’m not aware of any free SCORM RTE.  How much effort?  I’d say a week for the drop dead bare minimum that could pass as functional, and 2 years for doing it right.  You’re not just talking about JavaScript parts, you’d need a web API and a way to store student attempts (which it sounds like you need anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The SCORM Run Time Environment (RTE) is implemented using a heavily specified JavaScript object as the API. Storyline during launch will do a search based on a pre-defined algorithm for finding this object in the global namespace with a specific name (depending on the version of SCORM). The object stored in that namespace would only need to implement a tiny subset of the SCORM RTE API to receive the suspend data. For instance in SCORM 1.2 that object would need to have an `LMSSetValue` method that takes an element name, in this case `cmi.suspend_data` and the value (a string) and stores that value for future use. On the flip side, it would need to implement `LMSGetValue` such that when the element name, `cmi.suspend_data`, is requested the previously set value can be provided in return. How that data is stored to the server between sessions, etc. is implementation specific.

Naturally a course implemented against the SCORM specification will usually expect other functionality to exist in that API and your mileage may vary on how courses react to finding the object but not having the full implementation available.

There are also a number of ways to implement SCORM into a specific part of the system while letting someone else handle the SCORM implementation, [SCORM Cloud](https://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/) is an example of this with pay per use pricing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here is a how you can wrap RISE or StoryLine in an iframe and interact with the API, outside of using it with an LMS

The below code saves interactions to localstorage, like this progress is saved even between reloads

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }

            iframe {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                height    : calc(100vh - 4px);
                width     : calc(100vw - 0px);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- the below is for RISE, for storyline this would point to index_lms.html -->
        <iframe src="scormdriver/indexAPI.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <script>
            // Scorm 2004
            window.API_1484_11 = {
                Initialize: function () {
                    console.log("Initialize");

                    return "true";
                },
                Terminate: function () {
                    console.log("Terminate");

                    return "true";
                },
                GetValue: function (key) {
                    console.log("GetValue", key);

                    return localStorage.getItem(key) ?? "";
                },
                SetValue: function (key, value) {
                    console.log("SetValue", key, value);

                    localStorage.setItem(key, value);

                    // you can intercept values like this
                    switch (key) {
                        case "cmi.completion_status":
                            if (value == "completed") {
                                // call some function or web api here
                                //myFunction();
                            }
                    }                    

                    return value;
                },
                Commit: function () {
                    console.log("Commit");

                    return "true";
                },
                GetLastError: function () {
                    console.log("GetLastError");
                },
                GetErrorString: function (key) {
                    console.log("GetErrorString", key);
                },
                GetDiagnostic: function (key) {
                    console.log("GetDiagnostic", key);
                },
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```